# Defining a custom hash-function for boost hash map

Tags: c++, boost

I am very new to C++ and I need to convert some code written in C to C++. The problem is that I'm finding the C++ syntax pretty hard to comprehend on the fly. I wish to use the unordered boost hash map and I wish to define my own hash function. I looked up how to do so and I ran across this piece of code:

```
struct ihash
    : std::unary_function<std::string, std::size_t>
{
    std::size_t operator()(std::string const& x) const
    {
         std::size_t seed = 0;
         std::locale locale;

         for(std::string::const_iterator it = x.begin();
            it != x.end(); ++it)
         {
            boost::hash_combine(seed, std::toupper(*it, locale));
         }

         return seed;
    }
};

Which you can then use in a case insensitive dictionary:

boost::unordered_map<std::string, int, ihash, iequal_to> idictionary;
```

I have the following hash function:

```
unsigned long hash (unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while(c = *str++)
    hash  = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash + 33 + c */
    hash %= outer_relation->hash_table.bucket_count();

    return hash;
}
```

Can some one help me with the conversion. In particular, what are seed and combine responsible for?

Answer (score 1):

The first (`ihash`) is a general purpose hash, implemented in the form of a function object. This has several advantages:

- it's general-purpose, meaning, you can use it with hash tables of varying capacities/load factors without knowing/caring about the internal organization
- because it's a callable object, and it is default constructible, you can actually "just" instantiate the unordered map:

  ```
  boost::unordered_map<std::string, int, ihash, iequal_to> idictionary;
  ```

  which will then use a default-constructed instance of `ihash` as the hash function (same for`iequal_to`, for that matter).

The second looks like a hash function hardwired into a hash table implementation. Apparently this hash table implementation assumes all keys must be `unsigned char*`, and it derives a bucket index as part of the hash implementation. Notes:

- You cannot comfortably use this for default-constructible maps:

  ```
  boost::unordered_map<std::string, int, unsigned long(*)(unsigned char*), iequal_to> idictionary;
  ```

  as this would result in a `nullptr` instance for the hash function. So you'd end up passing `&hash` to a constructor overload all the time. It would be harder to reason about your code, as it's not impossible to pass the wrong function pointer, as long as the prototype matches
- This function assumes keys cannot contain embedded NUL characters (something that's not a restriction for `std::string`
- This function is not const-correct (meaning you couldn't make it work for `map` or `unordered_map` unless you added const, e.g. `size_t (*)(unsigned char const*)`).

Other than these observations, both functions do basically the same job, where `ihash` does case folding according to the global C++ locale ([see docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale)).

I'm not exactly sure where you're stuck because your sample looks like it should be relatively complete? So, here goes a little self-contained sample in case it helps you get unstuck:

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace hash_examples
{
    struct iequal_to
        : std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, bool>
    {
        iequal_to() {}
        explicit iequal_to(std::locale const& l) : locale_(l) {}

        template <typename String1, typename String2>
        bool operator()(String1 const& x1, String2 const& x2) const
        {
            return boost::algorithm::iequals(x1, x2, locale_);
        }
    private:
        std::locale locale_;
    };

    struct ihash
        : std::unary_function<std::string, std::size_t>
    {
        ihash() {}
        explicit ihash(std::locale const& l) : locale_(l) {}

        template <typename String>
        std::size_t operator()(String const& x) const
        {
            std::size_t seed = 0;

            for(typename String::const_iterator it = x.begin();
                it != x.end(); ++it)
            {
                boost::hash_combine(seed, std::toupper(*it, locale_));
            }

            return seed;
        }
    private:
        std::locale locale_;
    };
}

int main()
{
    using namespace hash_examples;
    boost::unordered_map<std::string, int, ihash, iequal_to> map;
    map.emplace("one",   1);
    map.emplace("two",   2);
    map.emplace("three", 3);

    std::cout << map.at("TWO");
}
```

Note that the `hash_examples` are directly from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/unordered/examples/case_insensitive.hpp

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e5378918c3f57d1)**

Answer (score -1):

If you want use your own hash why not implement ihash something like this?

```
struct ihash : std::unary_function<std::string, std::size_t> {
  std::size_t operator()(std::string const& value) const {
    std::size_t hash = 5381;
    const char* str = value.c_str();
    int c;
    while(c = *str++)
    hash  = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash + 33 + c */
    hash %= outer_relation->hash_table.bucket_count();
    return hash;
  }
}
```

Comment: because it would not be case insensitive (despite the name), and there is no `outer_relation` in the C++ hash table implementation. For starters. (Leaving out the detail that it's poor design to implement a general purpose hash using implementation details of the hash table, IMO)